# How can i just add meta key to new registered user

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

How can i add to every new user who register this meta key...instead of updating all users to value 0 again..just to assign this meta key and value 0 to the new user who register

```
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users" );
if( $users ) {
  foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'dospjeli_dug', 0 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use hook for it. `user_register` hook will do it.

```
add_action('user_register','addneumeta', 10, 1);

    function addneumeta($user_id){
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dospjeli_dug', 0 );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it to only new register user then [according to documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/) you need to use this function.

```
add_user_meta( $user_id,  'dospjeli_dug',  0);
```